Stop slider when infinite: false, React-Slick Slide
Guyes, i am learning react. working on a nextjs page.
using react-slick to slide name, categories etc.
when i click next it still going backward , look at this. and creating space. I think this should be stop at end. when infinite is set to: false. Inspired from this site to achieve this slider.

my setting. please check setup on Stackblitz 
const CategoryScroller = () => {
  const settings = {
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 500, 
      initialSlide: 0,
      centerPadding: '0px',
      variableWidth: true, // Enable variable width 
      nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow className={undefined} style={undefined} onClick={undefined} />,
      prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow className={undefined} style={undefined} onClick={undefined} />,
    responsive: [ 
    ],
  };

<div className='container'>
    <div className="slickcont">
      <Slider {...settings}>
        {categories.map((category, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="filterChip" style={{ width: 'auto' }}>
          <a href={category.link}>{category.name}</a>
        </div>
        ))}
      </Slider>
            </div>
            </div>

I tried to set min width to slide-track, but i broke markup.
